# JavaScript date format accepted by the date value returned from C#

Tags: c#, .net, javascript

Any one help to to get the extact value from the JavaScript date time utc format. I am using a C# web method which is returning a date and I have to set that date with Timezone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code below:

```
<script language="javascript">
ourDate = new Date();
document.write("The time and date at your computer's location is: "
+ ourDate.toLocaleString()
+ ".<br/>");
document.write("The time zone offset between local time and GMT is "
+ ourDate.getTimezoneOffset()
+ " minutes.<br/>");
document.write("The time and date (GMT) is: "
+ ourDate.toGMTString()
+ ".<br/>");
</script>
```

HTH

Comment: JavaScript date format accepted by the date value returned from C# ?

If i print both have exact value.
Example 
JavaScript function fx() comparing value that is returning from C# both having a same format